# SettingWithCopyWarning message in Pandas/Python with df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, warnings

OBS: I've spent a few hours searching in SO, Pandas docs and a few others websites, but couldnt understand where my code isnt working.

### My UDF:

```
def indice(dfb, lb, ub):
    dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
    dfb = dfb[~dfb.isOutlier]

    dfb['indice'] = (dfb['valor_unitario'] - lb) / (ub - lb) * 2000
    df = df.astype({'indice': 'int64'})
    return dfb
```

#### Important:

- `isOutlier` column **does not exist**. I'm creating it right now in this function.
- `indice` column **does not exist**. I'm creating it right now in this function.
- `valor_unitario` exists and its a float
- `lb` and `ub` are previously defined
- This function is inside a loop in the main code (but this warning is raised since n=0)

#### Warning raised

```
C:\Users\...\calculoindice_support.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

I found a few articles and questions on web and also StackOverflow saying that using `loc` would solve the problem. I tried but with no success

### 1º try - Using loc

```
def indice(dfb, lb, ub):
->  dfb.loc[:,'isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
    dfb = dfb[~dfb.isOutlier]

->  dfb.loc[:,'indice'] = (dfb['valor_unitario'] - lb) / (ub - lb) * 2000
    df = df.astype({'indice': 'int64'})
    return dfb
```

**I also tried to use loc each one each time** *actually, I tried a lot of possible combinations... Tried to use `df.loc` in `dfb['valor_unitario']` and so on*

**Now I have the same warning, twice, but a bit different:**

`self._setitem_single_column(ilocs[0], value, pi)` and
`self.obj[key] = value`

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Indice\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1676: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
-> self._setitem_single_column(ilocs[0], value, pi)
```

**and**

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Indice\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1597: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
-> self.obj[key] = value
```

I also tried using copy. At first time this warning shown up, simple using `copy()` solved the problem, I dont know why now its not working (I just loaded more data)

### 2º Try - Using copy()

I tried to place `copy()` in three places, with no sucess

`dfb = dfb[~dfb.isOutlier].copy()`

`dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub).copy()`

`dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].copy().between(lb, ub)`

```
C:\Users\...\calculoindice_support.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

I have no more ideas, would appreciate a lot your support.

### ------- Minimun Reproducible Example --------

#### Main_testing.py

```
import pandas as pd
import calculoindice_support as indice # module 01
import getitemsid_support as getitems # module 02

df = pd.DataFrame({'loja':[1,4,6,6,4,5,7,8],
                   'cod_produto':[21,21,21,55,55,43,26,30],
                   'valor_unitario':[332.21,333.40,333.39,220.40,220.40,104.66,65.00,14.00],
                   'documento':['324234','434144','532552','524523','524525','423844','529585','239484'],
                   'empresa':['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','CDE','CDE','CDE']
                   })

nome_coluna = 'cod_produto'
# getting items id to loop over them
product_ids = getitems.getitemsid(df, nome_coluna)

# initializing main DF with no data 
df_nf = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(df.columns.values))

n = 0
while n < len(product_ids):
    item = product_ids[n]
    df_item = df[df[nome_coluna] == item]
    # assigning bounds to each variable
    lb, ub = indice.limites(df_item, 10)
    # calculating index over DF, using LB and UB
    # creating temporary (for each loop) DF
    df_nf_aux = indice.indice(df_item, lb, ub)
    # assigning temporary DF to main DF that will be exported later
    df_nf = pd.concat([df_nf, df_nf_aux],ignore_index=True)
    n += 1
```

#### calculoindice_support.py (module 01)

```
import pandas as pd

def limites(dfa,n):
    n_sigma = n * dfa.valor_unitario.std()
    mean = dfa.valor_unitario.mean()
    lb: float = mean - n_sigma
    ub: float = mean + n_sigma
    return (lb, ub)


def indice(dfb, lb, ub):
    if lb == ub:
        dfb.loc[:, 'isOutlier'] = False
        dfb.loc[:, 'indice'] = 1
    else:
        dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
        dfb = dfb[~dfb.isOutlier]

        dfb['indice'] = (dfb['valor_unitario'] - lb) / (ub - lb) * 2000
        # df = df.astype({'indice': 'int64'})

    return dfb
```

#### getitemsid_support.py (module 02)

```
def getitemsid(df, coluna):
    a = df[coluna].tolist()
    return list(set(a))
```

#### Warning output:

```
C:\Users\...\calculoindice_support.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Indice\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1597: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = value
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Indice\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1720: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)
```

```
C:\Users\...\calculoindice_support.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
C:\Users\...\calculoindice_support.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

Comment: What's your version of pandas? I can't reproduce this error in 1.2.4.

Comment: HI @Ynjxsjmh, I'm not so sure, but I think it is 1.1.3. I opened Anaconda Prompt, >> Python >> import pandas as pd >> pd.show_versions(). I'm using PyCharm, with Conda Interpreter. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I upgraded to 1.2.4 and the 'warning' keeps happening!

Comment: Could you create a MRE? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for reference.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I'll do it as soon as possible and edit the main question. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Added MRE, I hope that it can help to understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: Don't know what you want to do. You can fix this warning by changing `indice` method to `def indice(df, lb, ub)` then add `dfb = df.copy()`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh ```def indice(df, lb, ub):
    dfb = df.copy()
 ....
```

Yep, it worked, no more warnings. Thanks. Can you explain why does it work? And feel free to reply the question so that I can choose your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your `Main_testing.py`

```py
while n < len(product_ids):
    df_item = df[df[nome_coluna] == item]

    df_nf_aux = indice.indice(df_item, lb, ub)
```

First you slice your `df` with condition `df[nome_coluna] == item`，this will return a copy of dataframe(You can check this by accessing `_is_view` or `_is_copy` attribute). Then you pass that filtered dataframe to `indice` method.

```py
def indice(dfb, lb, ub):
    dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

In `indice` method, you assign a new column to the filtered dataframe. This is an implicit chained assignment. Pandas don't know if you want to add the new column to the original dataframe or only add to the filtered dataframe, so pandas gives you a warning.

To suppress this warning, you can explicitly tell pandas what you want to do

```py
def indice(dfb, lb, ub):
    dfb = dfb.copy()
    dfb['isOutlier'] = ~dfb['valor_unitario'].between(lb, ub)
```

In the above case, I create a copy of filtered dataframe. This means I would like to add the new column to the filtered dataframe not original.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks.